# can I provide URL to SDWebImageCache which returns image either from cache or download?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImageCache I got a requirement where I need to provide an URL where it should automatically download the image asynchronously and if it is in cache it should get from cache.

I have observed we can set image to imageView with URL but did not found any method which asynchronously downloads and gives UIImage in return.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a more extensive documentation for SDWebImage [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/4.1.2/index.html).

For downloading an image directly without the use of a category you will need to use [SDWebImageManager](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/4.1.2/Classes/SDWebImageManager.html)

For downloading the image and getting the same in a closure, use the [`loadImageWithURL:options:progress:completed:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/4.1.2/Classes/SDWebImageManager.html#//api/name/loadImageWithURL:options:progress:completed:) method.

For just caching the image you can use the [`saveImageToCache:forURL:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/4.1.2/Classes/SDWebImageManager.html#//api/name/saveImageToCache:forURL:) method.